# What the proper word order in the sentence?

Tags: word-order, numbers

Sentence:

1. > How can I translate **their two** examples
2. > How can I translate **two their** examples

What the proper word order for the sentence?

Comment: The number goes next to thing it's counting, so 1 is correct.

Comment: 2) needs to be "How can I translate two **of** their examples?" It would be better if you explain why you changed the word order, rather than just ask which is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As User3169 and SteveES commented the 1st version is correct.

You can either say *"How can I translate their two examples"* or *"How can I translate two of their examples"*. If there are only two then you can use the word **both**.